# How to use Subtitles/Captions with MediaElement.js module

Tags: media, files

Would anyone have some direction to upload subtitles/captions using the [MediaElement.JS module](https://www.drupal.org/project/mediaelement)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MediaElement module](https://www.drupal.org/project/mediaelement) doesn't support it. In order for ME.js to [display subtitles](http://mediaelementjs.com/#highlighter_568360), you need to add a `<track>` element (e.g. `<track kind="subtitles" src="subtitles.srt" srclang="en" />`). The module's theme function, [`theme_mediaelement_video()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/mediaelement/tree/mediaelement.module?h=7.x-1.2#n167), doesn't render that element.

In lieu of this, you can override the theme function to add the required `<track>` element. For example placing this in your theme's **template.php**:

```
//Here we're assuming an .srt with the same name of the video exists alongside 
//(e.g. "sites/default/files/video.mp4 & sites/default/files/video.mp4.srt)
//Given you might want to upload srt files along with content
// you'll want a better solution

function MYTHEME_mediaelement_video($variables) {
  $output = '<div class="mediaelement-video">';
  $output .= '<video ' . drupal_attributes($variables['attributes']) . ' >';
  $output .= '<track kind="subtitles" src="' . $variables['attributes']['src'] . '.srt" />';
  $output .= '</video>';
  if ($variables['settings']['download_link']) {
    $output .= '<div class="mediaelement-download-link"><a href="' . $variables['attributes']['src'] . '">' . filter_xss_admin($variables['settings']['download_text']) . '</a></div>';
  }
  $output .= '</div>';
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: How can I add this functionality to the fullscreen version?

Comment: The full screen version works the same as the smaller player.